# TypeScript - how to type an object of interfaces with dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, object, types, interface

I'm just starting to use typeScript, and I try to type some data I get from my API.

[EDIT]
If my API send me an array of "simple" company objects, like that:

```
"companies": [
  {
    "id": "foo",
    "label": "Foo",
    "someNumber": 20,
    "someOtherNumber": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "bar",
    "label": "Bar",
    "someNumber": 20,
    "someOtherNumber": 0
  }
]
```

I would have a `CompanyInterface` like this:

```
export interface CompanyInterface {
  label: string,
  someNumber: number|null,
  someOtherNumber: number,
}
```

And I could do this: `private companies: Array<CompanyInterface> = [];`

BUT, my API send me a list of companies that are objects indexed by dynamic keys:

```
"companies": {
  "foo": {
    "label": "Foo",
    "someNumber": 20,
    "someOtherNumber": 3
  },
  "bar": {
    "label": "Bar",
    "someNumber": 20,
    "someOtherNumber": 0
  }
}
```

And my Interface looks like that:

```
export interface CompanyInterface {
  [key: string]: {
    label: string,
    someNumber: number|null,
    someOtherNumber: number,
  }
}
```

So what is the best way to type my `companies` property?

[info]
I tried @aleksxor 's answer: `private companies: CompanyInterface = {}` and I don't have any TS error. Is it what I should keep in my code?

Comment: It's not completely clear what are you trying to achieve. But the value of the `companies` key in your first code snippet is an object. And if you want to store this value into a variable it will look like: `private companies: CompanyInterface = {}`.

Comment: If `CompanyInterface` was a "simple" object (without `[key: string]`) then my API response would be an array of companies that I would type like this: `Array<CompanyInterface>`. But as it's an object of Companies, I didn't know how to type it. But your answer seems to work! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use type Record

`export type CompanysType = Record<string, YourType|Interface>`

Comment: Should I remove `[key: string]:` from my interface with your solution?

Comment: @Pochwar yes, just `Record<keyType, ValueType>` - standard type for dictionary.
In your case it will be `type CompanyType = Record<string, {
    label: string,
    someNumber: number|null,
    someOtherNumber: number,
  }>`